# Delivery status notification to document owner after sending mail with Google MailApp.sendMail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a google spreadsheet using [Course Registration Template](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AjbZnjlHMPF0dEtpcTYxRlQ5UlpXZWtiV3JuRDBHYUE&mode=public)

The script uses `MailApp.sendMail` to send mails. I haven`t modified it.

The owner of the document in drive.google.com is `course@mydomain.com`.

When a user registers for a course s/he receives a confirmation email and I receive an mail at `course@mydomain.com` that says:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>      course@mydomain.com
>
> Technical details of permanent failure: 
> The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or unnecessary spaces. Learn more at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596

How come I receive a message at `course@mydomain.com` that says that a message to `course@mydomain.com` can not be received?

Comment: I have just created an issue at code.google.com - https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4307&thanks=4307&ts=1409062162

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I originally did not set up a gmail acocunt. I used my hotmail address. I was getting Delivery Status Notification failure messages every time I used GmailApp.sendEmail.
Yesterday I setup gmail on my account. Now the call works fine. No errors.
Try associating your account with a gmail address and see if that works.